# Teradata view/sub-query spool consideration

Tags: teradata

In case of complex teradata query with subquery/view, Teradata materialize view/sub-query in spool.

My question is while doing this which column it uses to distribute such data? First column of sub-query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at Explain. A spool is either:

- **built locally**: no distribution, data is simply moved directly to a spool on each AMP
- **duplicated**: data is copied to each AMP
- **redistributed by the hash code of (...)**: now this is distributed, the list of columns is provided in the **(...)**